# Showing the first image from a nested array in angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs

This is my json. I need to show only the first image in my imageview. i tried with `{{p.url}}` to get the images. but its not worked fine.

```
 [{

        "comment": "",
        "adoptId": null,
        "images": [
          {
            "id": 4,
            "name": "3_1.jpg",
            "url": "Content\\RacePictures\\YRMTH-2017-04-15-HT09.jpg"
          },
          {
            "id": 5,
            "name": "3_2.jpg",
            "url": "Content\\RacePictures\\YRMTH-2017-04-15-HT09.jpg"
          }
        ]
```

HTML

```
    <div class="" ng-repeat="d in photos">
     <div class="col-md-6" >
    <div ng-repeat="p in d.images">
    <img ng-src="http://localhost:20513/{{p.url}}" />
  </div>
```

Angular Controller

```
    var httpRequest = $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: urls.api + 'Library/treeImages/Filter/' + images,
      }) .success(function (data, status) {
    $scope.photos = angular.fromJson(data);
                            }
)
}
```

Comment: try this `<img ng-src="http://localhost:20513/{{d.images[0].url}}" />`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just remove the ng-repeat and access the image array by the index

```
<div class="" ng-repeat="d in photos">
     <div class="col-md-6" > 
    <img ng-src="http://localhost:20513/{{d.images[0].url}}" />
 </div>
```

Comment: @Coder no prob machan

Answer (score 2):

```
<div class="" ng-repeat="d in photos">
   <div class="col-md-6" >
       <img ng-src="http://localhost:20513/{{d.images[0].url}}" />
   </div>
</div>
```

try this

Comment: <div ng-repeat="p in d.images"> 
with this line it showing the all the images bro. actually we dont need this line.

Comment: Updated the answer. :)